# How to use a scheduled event in a cloud notebook to read data files on a desktop

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I don't know even how to attempt this, or if it's possible. I would like to be able to examine conditions, data, status of email server on my work desktop from the programming cloud. I recognize that these are three different things (is an application running? does a file xxx.xls have data for something? are processes connected to the desktop running?). One might be do-able and the others not, so to be specific, I would like to be able to check for data, and maybe start applications on my desktop from the cloud.

I this even possible?

Comment: You can deploy a "dashboard" in the cloud, for sure, but you will have to upload the data periodically. You could do this by running a local scheduled task (keeping MMA running on the workstation of course), or some other scripting solution using WSTP.

Comment: @mfvonh I think this must be the only approach.  Wow-long time ago!